# Adding new filetype to NERD Commenter

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218). I want to add a new filetype to it. In the latest version, the filetypes definitions start in line 69. I want to add delimiters for .pde (Arduino). Since .pde files follow the same style as C++, I'm just copying the C++ line (line 115) and changing the extension. It looks like this:

```
....    
....    
\ 'pde': { 'left': '//', 'leftAlt': '/*', 'rightAlt': '*/' },
....    
....
```

And that seems right. However, I cannot get it to work when I open a .pde file. Instead of using '//', it uses '#'. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

UPDATE: It seems I'm doing it write. Look at the commit for when they added [commenting support for gsp](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/commit/c0d7109c6ba18ecf3dd53ef124dfc56068b76c61). They are just doing the same as me. Hmmm....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably because the filetype `pde` does not exist in filetype.vim.

Basically you have to  create you own filetype.vim  in ~/.vim/ (which will be sourced before the system filetype.vim), or add to your .vimrc:

`" Arduino files

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.pde   setf pde`

(On the other hand, `gsp`does already exist in the default filetype.vim on line 763

`" GNU Server Pages

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.gsp   setf gsp`
 
)

See `:help new-filetype` for more information on ways to implement a new file type.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks! I decided to name the filetype to 'arduino'. After all, the extension might be .pde, but the filetype is arduino. Thanks! :D